# Translating wrong colors back to their intended r, g and b values

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, aforge

This picture shows the problem

[image]
See the full sized picture at https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKqe0.jpg

Every pixel that should show a higher brightness resp. whose r, g or b values come close to 255 turns into pink or green.

The most promising filter I found is the EuclideanColorFiltering by Aforge. But it is inverted, ie it only shows the pink & green.

There is presumably a pattern in the picture that can be translated back into the right color.

The question is: how do I make the picture look the way it should look like, ie blue skyes are blue etc. using Aforge's filters or how do I translate the colors back properly?

This is the code I am currently using:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string path = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        // create video source
        videoSource = new VideoFileSource(path);
        // set NewFrame event handler
        videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);
        // start the video source
        videoSource.Start();
    }
}

private void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = eventArgs.Frame;

    EuclideanColorFiltering filter = new EuclideanColorFiltering();
    // set center colol and radius
    filter.CenterColor = new RGB(215, 30, 30);
    filter.Radius = 100;
    // apply the filter
    filter.ApplyInPlace(bitmap);

    if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
        pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
    pictureBox1.Image = bitmap.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    //pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
    // process the frame
}
```